# Changing a line dimensions in svg with jquery

Tags: jquery, svg, scroll

I have this svg that draws a simple line:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="80px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 80 589" enable-background="new 0 0 80 589" xml:space="preserve">

 <line fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1000" y2="1500"/>

</svg>
```

I want to be able to change x1, y1, x2, and x1 as a function of  the scroll position for a website. I'm stuck because I've only been able to alter css attributes, and these are not.

I was trying something along these lines:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    //calculate how far down the page the user is 
    var $percentageComplete = (($(window).scrollTop() / ($("html").height() - $(window).height())) * 100);
    var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", 200)
      .attr("height", 200);

    var line = svgContainer.append("line")
      .attr("x1", 15)
      .attr("y1", '' + $percentageComplete + '')
      .attr("x2", 30)
      .attr("y2", 20);
    document.getElementById("currentValue").innerHTML = $percentageComplete;

  });
  console.log("Ready");
});
```

This didn't work, I was able to make the scroll going and change a value as I went on the site, but I'm a little stuck when wanting to make the coordinates of the line as a function of the scroll.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, I'm using c3.js but I think it's same as d3 chart.

```
$.each($x_axis, (i, el) => {
                    $(el).find('.tick > text').attr("style", "text-anchor: start;").attr("style", "display: block;").attr("style", "transform: rotate(90deg) translate(15px, 0px);");
                    let $ticks = $(el).find('.tick');
                    $.each($ticks, (j, els) => {
                        var temp = $(els).attr('transform').split(' ');
                        var origin_transform = temp[0].slice(0,-1);
                        $(els).attr('style', 'opacity: 1;').attr('style', 'transform: ' + origin_transform + "px, -4px);");
                        $(els).find('line').attr('y2', '8');
                    });
                });
```

attr('y2', '8') it's working!

Answer (score 0):

The code in your question is d3, not jQuery. But assuming you were asking about jQuery, it doesn't (yet) work well with SVG. However, this should work:

```
$('line')[0].setAttribute('y1', newY1);
```

or plain JS:

```
document.querySelector('line').setAttribute('y1', newY1);
```